# program crashes while loading project or build application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

When I try to run or build my application I am getting the following error:

```
Faulting application name: MSDEV.EXE, version: 6.0.9782.2, time stamp: 0x40400977
Faulting module name: devncb.pkg, version: 6.0.8168.0, time stamp: 0x3588a3b6
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000ecff
Faulting process id: 0x116c
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf4a5b10f241ca
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\MSDev98\Bin\MSDEV.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\MSDev98\Bin\IDE\devncb.pkg
Report Id: 77fc74a1-b64e-11e3-894a-d4bed9e13763
```

I am using `Microsoft visual c++ 6.0`. I have tried excluding my program under DEP but I still get the same issue. I also get the error when I try to open it in my workspace.

Comment: `devncb.pkg` suggests a problem with the .ncb file. Since this is a temporary file, you could try deleting it and then restarting VC6.

Comment: well i regularly deleting temp memory..could you tell me where i can find .ncb file .

Comment: i just tried deleting .ncb file ..still the same issue.